# Do US military aircraft have tail numbers beginning with "N"?

Tags: military

Military aircraft usually display a serial number along with other insignia on the tail or body of the aircraft, [as described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_military_aircraft_serials).  However military serial numbers are not the same as FAA tail numbers on civilian US aircraft, which begin with the letter "N".

Do military aircraft also have an "N" number, or do US military aircraft simply not have an "N" number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 'N' numbers you're referring to are [FAA registration numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration#United_States). The FARs (Federal Aviation Regulations) specifically mention registration as not being required for military aircraft:

[14 CFR 47.3](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=8517c4b02d4f72e5f49c2c9c51562d37&mc=true&node=se14.1.47_13&rgn=div8)

> (b) No person may operate an aircraft that is eligible for registration under 49 U.S.C. 44101-44104, unless the aircraft—
>
> (1) Has been registered by its owner;
>
> (2) Is carrying aboard the temporary authorization required by §47.31(c); or
>
> (3) **Is an aircraft of the Armed Forces**

The FAA issues these registrations in accordance with its responsibilities under the [Chicago Convention on International Civil Aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation), which required (in [Article 20](http://www.icao.int/safety/airnavigation/NationalityMarks/article20_doc7300_en.pdf)) that:

> Every aircraft engaged in international air navigation shall bear its appropriate nationality and registration marks.

As per the above-cited 14 CFR 47.3, though, the U.S. specifically requires that all eligible aircraft have registrations unless it's either a military aircraft or it has temporary authorization under 14 CFR 47.31(c).

Comment: You cite both FAA regs and the history of those regulations from a 1947 aviation convention: +1 sir!

Comment: The FAA shares more history about N numbers [here](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/aircraft_nnumber_history/).

Comment: The military uses buno (beuno?) numbers to identify specific aircraft.  An aircrafts side number may change over its history, but the buno number remains constant.

Comment: BuNo = bureau number, a unique serial number used by the navy, assigned sequentially.  army and air force use a similar system, 6 or 7 digits long where the first two digits is the year of acquisition, followed by 4 or 5 digits unique to each year grouping.  actually putting this number on the aircraft seems to follow several different standards.

Answer (score 8):

As @reirab explained, "N" registration numbers are generally used for civilian aircraft.  However, there are some notable exceptions.

The [de Havilland DHC-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Canada_Dash_7) (aka "Dash-7", variously nomenclatured O-5A, EO-5B/C, or RC-7B) is used by the United States Army as its [Airborne Reconnassaince-Low](http://www.globalsecurity.org/intell/systems/arl.htm) manned aerial imagery intelligence platform.

[image]
<sup>Image credit: [Alan Radecki](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Akradecki) / [Wikimedia Foundation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Arl-dash7-N158CL-010515-01.jpg)</sup>

Another de Havilland, this one a [DHC-6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Canada_DHC-6_Twin_Otter), is used by the Air Force Academy's parachuting team:

[image]
<sup>Image credit: [Ian Tate](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ian_tate/) / [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ian_tate/16027885459)</sup>

Dover AFB's 436 Force Support Squadron employs several Cessnas at their Aero Club, used for [flight training](http://www.doverafb436fss.com/pages/main-website/leisure-activities/aero-club/rates.php).  One of them made the news when it made an emergency landing [onto a local highway](http://www.flyingmag.com/technique/accidents/air-force-cessna-ends-delaware-highway).

[image]
<sup>Image credit: Adrian R. Rowan / [Dover AFB](http://www.dover.af.mil/shared/media/photodb/photos/2012%5C07%5C120329-F-MM982-002.jpg)</sup>

These are just a start.  Getting creative with search queries, you can also find [hundreds](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Name_Results.aspx?Nametxt=DEPARTMENT%20OF%20THE%20ARMY&sort_option=1&PageNo=1) of [other](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Name_Results.aspx?Nametxt=DEPARTMENT%20OF%20DEFENSE&sort_option=1&PageNo=1) [aircraft](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Name_Results.aspx?Nametxt=DEPARTMENT%20OF%20THE%20NAVY&sort_option=1&PageNo=1) [listed](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Name_Results.aspx?Nametxt=UNITED%20STATES%20ARMY&sort_option=1&PageNo=1) in the [FAA registration database](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/name_inquiry.aspx).

Virtually all of these are very special-purpose aircraft, with no munitions or other armament (aside from chaff/flare as in the case of the Dash 7).

---

And although not technically military (yet), it is common for developmental aircraft to be given civilian registration numbers during flight testing phases prior to final delivery.  This prototype [KC-46A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-46_Pegasus), painted mostly in military-style "livery", has registration number N461FT.

[image]
<sup>Image credit: Ken Fielding / [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:N461FT_4_Boeing_767-2C%282LK%29-KC-46A_Boeing_Aircraft_Co_%28USAF%29_PAE_29JUL15.jpg)</sup>

Comment: Interesting that the KC-46A needed an FAA registration prior to the US military taking ownership.

Comment: @steampowered Since it's technically not "an aircraft of the armed forces" until they actually sell it to the Air Force, it would run afoul of 14 CFR 47.3(b) if they didn't register it (or at least apply for the registration) before flight testing.

Comment: Good point with this answer, @erich. The FARs just say that the military isn't _required_ to get a registration number; they don't say that they can't get one.

Comment: And then there are probably aircraft that are owned by DoD but aren't part of the armed forces. VIP transports and such for non-military senior staff.